# migration from DXA 1.2 to DXA 1.5

Tags: dxa, dxa-java, dxa-1.5, sdl-tridion, spring

Could you please list out what all features are added in DXA 1.5 which are not present in DXA 1.2?

Also In my current project we have to migrate spring Web App project from DXA 1.2 to 1.5 so I need to know what all modulewise steps/sequence  are required to be done?

Answer (score 4):

You can follow the release notes, which are included in the documentation for each version

1.3
http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20DXA-v3/GUID-D3920FCA-F021-4CC6-8ECF-0E7B31C5AC90

1.4
http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20DXA-v4/GUID-D3920FCA-F021-4CC6-8ECF-0E7B31C5AC90

1.5
http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20DXA-v5/GUID-D3920FCA-F021-4CC6-8ECF-0E7B31C5AC90

Answer (score 4):

On top of what Chris mentioned, you will find a list of API changes of all previous versions in the documentation of DXA 1.5 http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20DXA-v5/GUID-7AAF6049-CAC4-4DA5-8128-3EDD4F0C9C50

Please also note that DXA 1.2 was the first Java version, so you will find quite a lot of changes in the project layout and source code in the next versions.